# How to link Views Bulk Operations and Bibliography modules in a home-made search engine?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am using [Bilbiography module](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio) to manage scientific publications on a website. 
The default search engine is nice but I would like to add a Views Bulk Operations function so users can choose specific nodes (tick the boxes on each line) and then export them to End Note or Bibtex, etc., like Bibliography does (export links at the top right).
Has anyone built a thing like this before in a View?
I would appreciate to have a few tips on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this sandbox module that add export functionality for all results in a view as a footer / header: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/szeidler/2394975